# Competition idea - thoughts?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions, competitions

I was wondering if we could get some more competition style activity into the site without affecting quality.

Was thinking about a last-man-out-wins style comp where basically each day you have to answer at least one question AND get positive upvotes to stay in the comp.

We could do either unanswered questions or any question (ie you could add an answer to a previous one).

Miss a single day and you're out, last person left wins?

Let me know if there's any flaws in that, or if you have other ideas.

(And before someone asks 'why': because sometimes, competitions are fun. You don't have to enter)

Comment: could also do one for bounties, but I'm not sure how that'd work if the bounties don't get answered

Comment: @pnuts good point for self answers.  Addressed the +1 below.  UTC doesn't favour any if it's for a 24 hour period, you just answer in your timezone.  We'd just get people to post links to their answers in community wiki answers for each day, so it can be monitored easily that way, I think?

Comment: Quite possibly because so much of our traffic is global about many countries that people are travelling to.

Answer (score 5):

Make it (Miss a **two days** and you're out, last person left wins)

This site is full with travelers who are simply can not be here everyday due to many factors, such as backpackers on remote areas, hitchhikers on the road for few days before they get internet, people whose jobs are travelling, etc. So the one day thing is not doable.

Make it two days, and I am in.

Comment: Not sure about that. It's a bit silly but 1 day is simple and elegant. It's tough to be sure but that's the game. 2 days is not much better – you can easily be away for three days – and just sounds arbitrary.

Comment: @Relaxed it is a fun competition, not a Nobel prize.. rules can be anything -- from silly to weird... that's the fun in it..

Comment: Silly and weird is good, arbitrary hurts my sense of aesthetics ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds fun.

You might want to specify if the question and the upvote have to happen on the same day or if you merely have to write an answer that eventually gets upvotes every day (not sure if I am clear ;-). Or are the upvotes and the answers completely disconnected (i.e. writing an answer and getting an upvote on some older pre-competition answer on a given day is enough)?

The first variant would be more difficult to achieve (you need to hope there are enough visitors who notice your answer to get an upvote before the end of the day) and to judge (because you need to know *when* an answer was upvoted) but at least you would know immediately who is in and who is out. In the second variant, a contestant could have a 0-vote answer by midnight and get a late upvote one or two days down the line.

And you also need to define what count as a day (UTC? Local time – but how do you know? Less than 24 hours between two answers?).

Comment: Well this is where @Menotalk's 2 day thing would come in I guess, it's easier to have some lee-way.  Basically if 48 hours pass between two upvotes of newly-answered questions, you're out?

Comment: @MarkMayo Could be a workable definition.

Comment: I'd tend to vote for 24/48 hours between two upvoted answers rather than having a time for the change of day (e.g. UTC).

Answer (score 0):

I would set a +500 bounty on each question that goes unanswered for a week. Most of them can be resolved by calling/emailing a travel/border agency in the respective country. For example [Getting to Shatili?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27286/getting-to-shatili-village-from-tbilisi) can be resolved by calling a travel agency in Tbilisi. [Can you access the Eurostar Business Premier lounge when going to Lille or Calais?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27133/at-brussels-midi-station-can-you-access-the-eurostar-business-premier-lounge-wh) can be resolved by calling Eurostar, and so on.

Comment: Who's setting this bounty?? ;)

Comment: I'd say we should tax the Top 1% of this society!

Comment: OK but I don't see the connection with Mark's idea.

Comment: @JonathanReez you're in the top 8% this month, not far off ;)

Comment: @Relaxed if the competition is about unanswered questions, this could be a way of distributing prizes.